# How to get Jquery Ajax Readystates

Tags: jquery, ajax

how can i know the readystates of an ajax request through jquery ?
In general, without using jquery, we will send an ajax request like this:

```
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

So i can easily track the readystate value from 1 to 4 using the above code, and perform necessary action like showing a loading icon when readystate is 1.

But through a jquery ajax call, how can i track the readystate values ?

I am making an ajax call through jquery like this:

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [**`$.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You have the possibility to pass different callbacks (maybe not for evert "ready state" but it is enough for an indicator):

> **`beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)`** *Function*
>   A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, `XMLHTTPRequest`) object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The `jqXHR` and `settings` maps are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning `false` in the `beforeSend` function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the `beforeSend` option will be called regardless of the type of request.
>
> **`success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`** *Function, Array*
>   A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The `data` returned from the server, formatted according to the `dataType` parameter; a string describing the status; and the `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, `XMLHttpRequest`) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an [Ajax Event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).
>
> **`error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`** *Function*
>   A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, `XMLHttpRequest`) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides `null`) are `"timeout"`, `"error"`, `"abort"`, and `"parsererror"`. This is an [Ajax Event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events). As of jQuery 1.5, the `error` setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.
>
> **`complete(jqXHR, textStatus)`** *Function, Array*
>   A function to be called when the request finishes (after `success` and `error` callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, `XMLHTTPRequest`) object and a string categorizing the status of the request (`"success"`, `"notmodified"`, `"error"`, `"timeout"`, `"abort"`, or `"parsererror"`). As of jQuery 1.5, the `complete` setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an [Ajax Event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).

So the best idea would be to show the indicator in the callback passed to `beforeSend` and hide it in `complete`.

---

**Example:**

So you would have to rewrite your code as:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function() {
       // show indicator
  },
  complete: function() {
      // hide indicator
  },
  success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
  }
});
```

although I don't understand why you use POST as your are not sending any data (at least in your example code).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you post an example of how to use it in my sample jquery POST call mentioned in my question?

Comment: @dskanth: I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, actually i have to send some parameters via post, but i did not include them in this example.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$.ajax({
 url:,
success:function(){

}//This is ready state 4
});
```

`perform necessary action like showing a loading icon when readystate is 1.`

for that you may use [**ajaxStart**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [**ajaxStop**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
I think you will find the different events here correspond to the different readyStates.