# How to recognize a ajax have submitted the request but waiting for a Response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I've an ajax request which will take more than 1 minute to get a response. User entered data will be submitted in that request.

So I've to show two success messages for the client like this.

1) "Data successfully submitted" after ajax send the data to server without receiving immediate response. If it immediately receives a response, it'll definitely be a error.
2) Now the user can wait in the same page for seeing the second success message "File generation successful" after the long process completion in server OR he can navigate to other pages or even he can logout. But it'll not affect the process running in the server because it'll be Asynchronous process running in a seperate thread.

But I dont know how to recognize that ajax have sent the data to server but waiting to receive a response? I can simply show the success message by

```
function sendData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: ...,
        data: ...,
        success: function(data){
            $("#success-message").html("File genration sucessfull");
        }
    });
    $("#success-message").html("Data successfully submitted");
}
```

But the "data successfully submitted" will be shown even if the client is disconnected from the internet. That's why I need to show this "Data successfully submitted" message after ajax request when the ajax is in pending state to receive an response.

Comment: i think you need similer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755885/how-do-i-make-jquery-wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-finish-before-it-returns

Comment: @ManishShukla, No.. It's not related to my question.

Comment: Use `beforeSend` as `success`. Before ajax started to work, you can show a popup for the user. It means, now the sending will start. And also use an `error` case, to catch errors.

Comment: Isn't this answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455281/how-to-get-jquery-ajax-readystates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the current solution, just make sure to write an error handler. If the user is disconnected from the internet, the error handler will trigger almost immediately after the function returns so the browser would most likely not even render the success message.

E.g:

```
function sendData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: ...,
        data: ...,
        error: function(data){ // callback triggers almost directly after returning
            // "success-message" not a very good name
            $("#success-message").html("Error occurred");
        }, 
        success: function(data){
            $("#success-message").html("File generation successful");
        }
    });
    $("#success-message").html("Data successfully submitted");
}
```

Comment: Damn, why didn't I think like that. Sometimes its irritating when missed a simple logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax is asynchronous `async:true;`
You always have call back events for for.
e.g.,

```
success: function (json) { 
                              console.log('success:'+json) 
                             },
                             complete: function (msg,a,b) {
                                console.log('complete :'+msg) 
                             },
                             error : function(msg,a,b){
                                 console.log('error:'+msg);
                             }
```

Refer to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for more reference

Comment: Ajax is always asynchronous unless you specify it as `async : false;`